# How do you pass an object reference to a directive?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angular-directive

In my app, I have an `ng-repeat` that iterate through JSON and prints each object to the page. So for example, my `ng-repeat` prints the animals

```
[
              {
                   name: "horse",
                   sound: "Nay",
                   legs: 4,
              },
              {
                    name: "beaver",
                    sound: "thwack",
                    legs: 2
              }
]
```

I also want to pass each animal to a directive and possibly add some key, values to them. The problem is, when I add the animal object as an attribute and update it in the directive,

i.e.

```
<animal this-animal={{animal}}></animal>
```

and in the directives link function

```
var animalObj = scope.$eval(attrs.thisAnimal);
animalObj["gestation"] = 10;
```

it doesn't update in the original JSON. It's like it gets disconnected from the overall array of all animals.

Why? How do I keep it all together? I want updates to individual objects to make changes in the main JSON object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using {{model}} in html it will resolve that value and place it into the HTML. In your case the JSON is getting stringified and then coverted back thus making a cloned object. Instead of using {{model}} just pass the name of the value.

```
<div my-directive="model">
```

Then access the model value using $parse

```
module.directive('myDirective', function($parse) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var val = $parse(attrs.my directive)(scope);
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use isolate scope. Assuming the array of animals is a scope property of the parent controller, you can do this:

```
<div ng-repeat="animal in animals">
    <animal this-animal="animal"></animal>
</div>
```

And in the directive code:

```
module.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {

        scope: {
            thisAnimal: "="
        },

        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.thisAnimal.gestation = 10;
        }
    };
});
```

Refer the isolate scope section of this page for more details:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: Is this better than using `$parse`? Doesn't this mean I won't be able to use variables from the controller's scope?

Comment: yes, it means variables from controller scope can't be used directly. But for all the variables you need from controller, you can similarly create a isolate scope binding.

Comment: Can you explain, or point me to somewhere where I can see how to bind stuff from the controller into my directive?

Comment: It is exactly as shown in the answer. If you have a variable in controller scope, say, $scope.x, then in the directive in the html, you write <my-directive isolate-x="x" /> and in the scope property in the directive you add isolateX: "=isolateX" and in the link, use $scope.isolateX. For more on isolate scope, i am updating my answer with a link.